# Tips to structure this database

Tags: mysql, database, structure

I want to make a database for a plugin I am making for Minecraft.
I've been trying to figure the best way to structure this but I have failed many times, could anyone give me some tips?

The idea is:
There will be a `active_shops` table => this represents individual shops, saving the information about each shop.

I need a table called `player_shops` => this table will have an AI ID and store things like, members and the name of the shop.

Here is where the problem is, 
when adding the `active shop` I would need to include the ID from the `player_shops` as a secondary key.

But a player without a `player shop` can also make an `active shop` so instead of that ID I would need to store the player's UUID, which is a string of characters.

Please help to figure this out.

Comment: Does your player_shops and active_shops has a one to one mapping?

Comment: @ReazMurshed It has a many to one mapping, as in active_shops can have many player_shops.

Comment: Why do you need the player_shops id in the active_shops table then? I do not think its necessay.

Comment: @ReazMurshed So it can identify which name it should show, if from the player_shops or from the player's UUID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information provided is scarce so it might not apply to your context, but...

Your original DB structure looks like:

[image]

Besides the problem you stated, you will not be able to normalize this structure.

I propose something like this:

[image]

- The relation Shop - Player is to designate the "owner" of the shop.
- The Member link table is to link the players members of the shop.
- Since I do not know the difference between an active shop, and a player shop, I isolated that characteristic into a ShopType table, allowing you to choose one or the other.
- Doing it like this allows a player to have any type of shop he wants.  A shop is a shop, from your description I do not understand why you need to have 2 tables for your 2 shop types.  A shop is a shop, being Active or Player type.
- This is not a complete, add the different missing fields for each table, this illustrates only the structure.

The other possibility is if you need a shop to be 1) player 2) active 3) both.  Then the shop table should be modified like so:

[image]

- the type concept is removed, and boolean attributes define the type of the shop.

This is obviously a work in progress, hopefully it helps enough to get you started thinking of your solution another way.